# How do I create python environment variables in puppet using python::virtualenv?

Tags: python, environment-variables, puppet

I'm running a python script that interacts with Slack.  I'm getting the Slack api token into the python script with

```
the_token = os.environ.get('SLACK_TOKEN')
```

I tried to puppetize the python environment with

```
$var_name = 'SLACK_TOKEN'
$token = 'xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

python::virtualenv { $virtualenv_path:
  ensure       => present,
  requirements => '/opt/<dir>/<dir>/<dir>/requirements.txt'
  owner        => $::local_username,
  version      => '3',
  require      => [Class['<class>']],
  environment  => ["${var_name}=${token}"],
}
```

I thought the last line of the 'virtualenv' block would set the environment variable, but apparently not.

Comment: What Puppet python module are you using, I had a look at this one https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppet/python but couldn't see a  python::virtualenv type in there.

Comment: [link](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppet/python/reference#pythonvirtualenv) which has an 'environment' option

Answer (score 0):

In `manifests/virtualenv.pp` there is an exec that's running pip commands to install/start virtual environments (sorry, I'm no expert on Python virtual environments).

```
      exec { "python_requirements_initial_install_${requirements}_${venv_dir}":
        command     => "${pip_cmd} --log ${venv_dir}/pip.log install ${pypi_index} ${proxy_flag} --no-binary :all: -r ${requirements} ${extra_pip_args}",
        refreshonly => true,
        timeout     => $timeout,
        user        => $owner,
        subscribe   => Exec["python_virtualenv_${venv_dir}"],
        environment => $environment,  <----- HERE
        cwd         => $cwd,
      }
```

When the exec runs, Puppet opens a shell, pipes in the environment variables, runs the command and closes the shell so the environment variables exist within the shell Puppet started but not in the Python environment it created. It's intended function is probably to setup paths to commands if they are in a different place or pass in proxy configurations so pip can pull packages in from external sites.

I verified the exec is handling what your sending it correctly using this.

```
class test {

$var_name = 'test'
$token = 'xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

  exec { "test":
    command     => "/bin/env > /tmp/env.txt",
    environment => ["${var_name}=${token}"],
  }
}
```

But you'll notice I had to dump the environment the exec was running in out to a file to see it.